# Core Data entities using codegen causing "initializer required 'init(entity:insertInto:)' " error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a short chain of Core Data entities with one-to-many relationships:

- User has zero-to-many Tweets
- Tweet has zero-to-many MediaObjects (e.g. Photos attached to a tweet)
- MediaObjects have zero-to-many Variants (e.g. different mp4 encodings for videos)

Each entity on the 'to-many' end of a relationship also has a relationship back up to the owning entity; i.e. 'tweet' also has a to-one 'user' relationship, and media objects also have a 'tweet' relationship.

The many-to-one relationship seems to work fine for one level deep (user->tweet) but not for further levels (tweet->media or media->variant)

When I try to build, I get:

`/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-apwnbsxvzneyrubfissqvdylmkys/Build/Intermediates/PROJECT_NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECT_NAME.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/PROJECT_NAME/TweetMediaPhoto+CoreDataClass.swift:14:58: Initializer requirement 'init(entity:insertInto:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in non-final class 'TweetMediaPhoto'`

I thought this would be generated for me by XCode, and when I click through to the file in question there is a warning not to edit it directly:

```swift
//
//  TweetMediaPhoto+CoreDataClass.swift
//  
//
//  Created by David Godfrey on 22/03/2017.
//
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(TweetMediaPhoto)
public class TweetMediaPhoto: TweetMedia {

}
```

(although TweetMediaPhoto inherits from TweetMedia and does not inherit directly from NSManagedObject, I have tried refactoring the entities to duplicate out the properties that were in TweetMedia and made the hierarchy flat; this had no effect other than updating the signature to read `: NSManagedObject` in the generated code, while still showing the build error)

In fact Swift documentation outright states ["You are discouraged from overriding this method"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506357-init) even if I were to create my own classes.

What is causing this, and how can I fix this build error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a few issues related to a custom protocol, `KnownCoreDataEntity`.

1. The protocol required that the `NSManagedObject` initialiser `init(entity:insertInto:)` be available, and a number of entities implemented the protocol. I believe due to the fact that CoreData bridges with ObjC, the Swift compiler was *not* happy about this as it made requirements that technically might not be satisfied. Removing the explicit requirement for the init, and in stead extending the protocol with `extension KnownCoreDataEntity where Self: NSManagedObject {` allowed access to the initialiser.
2. Another error appearing was `A declaration cannot be both 'final' and 'dynamic'` - this was caused by the same protocol, requiring `static var EntityName: String { get }` - changing the static EntityName property to a `let` and/or marking the property with `@nonobjc` fixed this issue too.

I was using this protocol to reduce boilerplate when creating entities. A `create(withGivenContext:NSManagedObjectContext?)` method and `loadOrCreate(withId:Int64,andGivenContext:NSManagedObjectContext?)` method would handle retrieving the context if it wasn't provided, and deal with checking if an object existed or not; the callee often doesn't care if the entity needed to be created, it often just wants a reference it can start manipulating.